# Can’t access array item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this data coming back from a color picker when I select a donkey

Comment: `tinyColor[\'a\’];` uh? did you mean `tinyColor['a'];`?

Comment: you don't need to escape key quotes

Comment: You have `”` where there should be `"` and `’` where there should be `'`

Comment: No, I meant that, it is a script being injected into a live page and therefore needs those, else they are literal.. the whole code is wrapped in ‘ ’s

Comment: Read a javascript tutorial - this code has too many fundamental issues.

Comment: The code is a mess due to the screwy quote marks and escape slashes, but putting that aside, your object doesn't have an "a" property, but the "_originalInput" object within it does, so... `tinyColor._originalInput.a` might be what you want? BTW you haven't got any arrays here, only objects.

Comment: Since "_originalInput" appears as the object name that contains "a". Shouldn't the lookup be `tinyColor._originalInput.a`

Comment: @Marley I think ASDF is pointing out that these things are distracting from the actual question, and ought to have been fixed before posting. Explaining the fundamentals of JS syntax is not really the purpose on this site, since all that kind of thing is already documented.

Comment: Good guess, you could be right, or wrong lol

Comment: @Marley well it's true, you've generated a whole load of comments totally unrelated to what you wanted to know about, because you didn't format your stuff properly. Coders are generally pedantic, it's one of the things which makes them good at the task. Anyway...did you try the suggestion I made which actually was trying to help?

Comment: Just so you all know, this code is injected into a html page so those quotes that people are complaining about are necessary in order to not break the javascript that injects them, yes I should have taken them out but THAT is the reason, there is USUALLY a reason people do things.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what `a` is referring to but I assume you mean `_originalInput.a`.

Either way you can just access `a` using `tinyColor._originalInput.a`

```js
var tinyColor = {
  "_originalInput": {
    "h": "0%",
    "s": "0%",
    "v": "100%",
    "a": 0
  },
  "_r": 255,
  "_g": 255,
  "_b": 255,
  "_a": 0,
  "_roundA": 0,
  "_format": "hex",
  "_ok": true,
  "_tc_id": 248
}

var theCol = JSON.stringify(tinyColor); // strigify it to see it
console.log(theCol); // show me it
var a = tinyColor._originalInput.a; //get value of a from array
console.log(a); // alert a
```

Answer (score 5):

Your object is not invalid (Consists invalid token). After fixing that `tinyColor._originalInput.a` will give you the value of `a`:

```js
var tinyColor = {
  "_originalInput": {
    "h": "0%",
    "s": "0%",
    "v": "100%",
    "a": 0
  },
  "_r": 255,
  "_g": 255,
  "_b": 255,
  "_a": 0,
  "_roundA": 0,
  "_format": "hex",
  "_ok": true,
  "_tc_id":248
}

var a = tinyColor._originalInput.a; //get value of a from array
console.log(a); //logs 0
```